# How use gvim command history?

Tags: vim

When I close gvim, I can't press the up arrow to rerun the commands from my last vim session. How do I make it so that I can do this?

For example, I can type:

```
:set hls<CR>
:set<up arrow>
```

And I see:

```
:set hls
```

But when I close vim, typing

```
:set<up arrow>
```

does not show my last use of the set command.

Comment: If I've understood your question right -- you want command history to persist when you exit Vim and restart it, and that isn't happening at present -- then what you need is a `viminfo` file. What puzzles me is that I thought Vim used one by default, and saved command history in it by default. What OS are you on? What does Vim display if you say `:set viminfo`?

Comment: can't make any sense of this question

Comment: Why -ve votes, I think the question is valid one. +1

Answer (score 4):

After a new install of Xubuntu 13.10 I had no command history.  But I noticed that my .viminfo file in my home folder was owned by root.  Changing the owner and group of the file to my normal user fixed the problem.

Comment: Turns out this happens if you run vim for the first time using the `sudo` command, as is common when setting up a new box.

Answer (score 1):

You coud try  ''set history=[number]'' in .vimrc
Here is my configuration:

```
set history=50
set viminfo=%,'20,/100,:100,<500,f1,n~/.vim/viminfo
```

History is persistent now even when you close and reopen vim.

Comment: Could you explain what this is doing. For instance, I could not see in the help what f1 is doing, etc...